# How can I log TBW per process (even if not so accurate)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, software-rec, storage, samsung-ssd

One of my SSD's TBW is rising much more rapidly than the TBW on my other SSDs (for comparison: in 2 months I wrote more data than I did in a whole year and a half in another SSD).

While Task Manager and Resource Manager can show me immediate Read/Write **speeds**, they cannot register how much data was read or written through a period of time.

I'd like to know how I could somehow log (even if an external program is required) the **TBW by each process** (basically by summing up the Read/Write speeds as time passes) and **to which disk** it was read/written, even if approximately, only so I have an idea on what are the culprits of such issue.

OS: Windows 10 (running all latest updates)

Peace! ;)

Comment: In what OS are you looking for this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Windows (if you're not, please note that we only know what you tell us, and improve your question using the EDIT button provided), you can view I/O Writes per process in the Task Manager.

1. Open the **Task Manager** and select the **Details** tab
2. Right-click on the column headers and click **Select Columns**
3. Select **I/O writes bytes**

Comment: Whoops, shoot! Hadn't noticed I forgot to specify the OS, sorry.

Thanks for the thorough answer! ;)

Comment: @PhelpsW please click the checkmark next to my post to indicate it is the answer to your question.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I'm new to actually using (as opposed to simply consulting) SuperUser.
I guess I'm pretty late, but done ;)
And thanks again for the answer ;)